# Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: io.blinqpay.blinqpost

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uikit

i did a firebase user authentication on a project in ios, after running the project on a simulator to register a user, the alerts shows error message and also the console prints this

> Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: io.blinqpay.blinqpost due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled

what could be the problem? i have enabled keychain and done every other thing required.

this is the simulator error

[image]

this is error message in xcode console.

[image]